# Having a good streaming experience

Tags: django, nginx, video-streaming, html5-video, video.js

I am working on a project which involves uploading and streaming of videos by learners.The videos are hosted in the same server where my application is hosted.

My project is based on django, videojs and mysql. I am using nginx to serve the contents. My problem is the streaming experience is not very good. The video stalls after every few seconds.

What are some things I can do to enhance the streaming. I am aware I should be hosting the videos with service providers such as vimeo but for now I just want to host the videos locally.

Any advice are welcomed.

Comment: You can host your files on your server and still use a CDN (e.g. Amazon CloudFront) to serve the files. See my [blog post](https://www.dedi.co/blog/entries/2019/01/02/deploying-your-django-static-files-aws-partnbsp2) about how to set this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to host the videos with vimeo so that I do not reinvent the wheel since I can afford to pay for their package. Their APIs are also very helpful and well documented which was a plus. Thanks.